# How to cache github action that downloads and installs the software using source code like ruby/setup-ruby does?

Tags: github-actions

In the process of building and testing the ruby/rails app through github actions which uses Saga as the dependency that needs to get latest installed using the source code as follows which runs the following step successfully in my workflow.

```
        run: |
          sudo apt-get install git libwxgtk3.0-dev libtiff5-dev libexpat-dev wx-common libogdi3.2-dev unixodbc-dev
          cd /tmp
          git clone git://git.code.sf.net/p/saga-gis/code saga-gis-code
          cd saga-gis-code/saga-gis
          git checkout release-7.0.0
          autoreconf -fi
          ./configure
          make
          sudo make install
```

and on the last step it runs the specs `bundle exec rspec spec`.

But that git cloning, configure, make and install takes too long to get installed.

Is there a way to extract the step or cache it out like to reduce the time it takes since the release 7.0.0 will the be same on every push I make to the app?

Answer (score 0):

I think `actions/cache` may do what you want. You can read the documentation [here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/guides/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows).

Instead of cloning `saga-gis-code` into `/tmp` (because you might run afoul of its autodeletion rules, defeating the purpose of caching), you may want to instead clone it into the home directory. Then, you can set up caching in a separate step with something similar (I've left some placeholders in because I'm not sure of the specifics of your workflow) to the following:

```
# Generates cache
- uses: actions/cache@v2
    id: cache
    with:
      path: path/to/dependencies
      # modify the arg of `hashFiles()` below to point to the Ruby build artifacts
      key: ${{ runner.os }}-${{ hashFiles('**/lockfiles') }}

# If cache is hit, re-install dependencies
  - name: Install Saga
    if: steps.cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
    run: |
      autoreconf -fi
      ./configure
      make
      sudo make install
```

There are also some Ruby-specific examples in the `cache` [repo](https://github.com/actions/cache/blob/main/examples.md#ruby---bundler) that might be of interest to your scenario.